# Why does my electrical panel have 2 different breakers for Dryer?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, dryer, circuit

My dryer is labeled as a  single 30 amp breaker and a 15 amp breaker. Is this a total of 45 amp at the outlet? Or is it 30 amp for heat and 15 for some other electrical function on the dryer?

Comment: You say single 30 amp breaker - do you mean single pole (one breaker space) or a single breaker which could be single or double pole?  If you could, edit the post to include a photo of the electrical panel.

Comment: no it is not, each breaker serves different function and are not combined to serve the dryer. Only 30 Amp serves the dryer while the 15 Amp is for the wall outlet in the launday room next to the dryer.

Comment: Either register your account so you can switch devices, or from this same browser post a picture of your panel.  "single 30A" is patently incorrect, unless it's Square D QO, in which case it'll be ["weird"](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=166).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica do you mean a single pole 30A is weird? Because they are used fairly commonly for TT30 plugs. If you're talking about 30A single pole for a dryer being weird, yeah, totally agree there.

Comment: @KMJ I meant single-pole 30A is weird *for a dryer*, however, now that you mention it, TT30 plugs for RVs is *the only other use* I have ever found for a 30A single-pole.

Comment: @KMJ I assumed he meant that a Square D QO 2-pole technically has the same little single-pole handle even though it is 2 poles wide.

Comment: Just because somebody wrote "dryer" in a couple places on your panel doesn't  mean you have a 75 amp appliance. How is the dryer actually connected?

Comment: @KMJ sorry yes, I meant the QO doesn't have a double handle that is tied.  Lost the thread lol.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel please?

Answer (score 5):

If both breakers are single pole, you may have an issue that needs to be corrected.

If the 30A breaker is a 2 pole and the 15A breaker is single pole, your house might just have a circuit for each of the two most popular types of dryer.  Depending on where your house is located and when it was built, the prevailing heat source could have been gas or electric - most houses will have one or the other, but some will have both.

**Electric Dryer Outlet**

An electric dryer uses a 240/120V circuit, which provides both voltages in the same receptacle.  It draws 240V for the heating element and 120V for the control electronics.  A 240/120V circuit has a 30A 2-pole circuit breaker in the panel, 10AWG wire, and has a receptacle that looks like this:

[image]

**Gas Dryer Outlet**

A gas dryer, however, only needs 120V to run the control electronics (the heat is provided by gas), so it typically plugs into a regular 120V circuit with our extremely common little buddy, NEMA 5-15.

[image]

In modern electrical code, this would be part of the generic "laundry" circuit for both washer and dryer.  It would be fed by a 20A single-pole breaker at the electrical panel and 12 AWG wire.  However, in an older home it could possibly be 15A and 14AWG depending on what year the house was built and what version of the code was in force at the time.

If you have both circuits, you have more options at the appliance store.